# OpenAL blocking OpenGL from displaying graphics

Tags: c, opengl, openal

Since i am very new to openAL i am unable to simultaneously display and play sound in 
this program. Can someone please help me out on this.

The code includes both openAL and openGL files in the same .c file.

Thanks.

```
#include <AL/al.h>
//#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <AL/alut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include<GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

//gcc -lopenal -lalut -lGL -lGLU -lglut filename.c -lm
#define FILENAME "clap.wav"

void display(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
  ALuint buffer, source;
    ALuint state;

   // Load pcm data into buffer

   buffer = alutCreateBufferFromFile(FILENAME);


    // Create sound source (use buffer to fill source)
    alGenSources(1, &source);
    alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);
    //glutPostRedisplay();
    // Play
    alSourcePlay(source);

    // Wait for the song to complete
    do {
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    } while (state == AL_PLAYING); 

    // Clean up sources and buffers
    alDeleteSources(1, &source);
    alDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);

    // Exit everything
    alutExit();

glFlush ();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

 glutInit(&argc,argv);


    // Initialize the environment
    alutInit(&argc,argv);

    // Capture errors
    alGetError();

    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("Greeting");
  //init ();
 glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't do all the OpenAL work in the display func. It is called every frame.

Comment: @LumpN That's an answer, and a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split up loading the sound, playing the sound and clearing the buffer.
But your issue currently is, that you're looping inside your display function until the sound has finished playing! So of course you won't see anything rendered until then.

Also you should not load/delete the sound every time the display function is called - just load it once: and then play it inside your display() function.
If you're done with the sound you can delete it. But keep in mind, that you have to load it again to play it again - so probably you want to leave it inside the memory and just delete it at your program termination.

However this snippet will load the sound, play it once (keep rendering) and delete it.

```
#include <AL/al.h>
//#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <AL/alut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

//gcc -lopenal -lalut -lGL -lGLU -lglut filename.c -lm
#define FILENAME "clap.wav"

ALuint buffer, source; 
void loadSound(){
  // Load pcm data into buffer
  buffer = alutCreateBufferFromFile(FILENAME);
  // Create sound source (use buffer to fill source)
  alGenSources(1, &source);
  alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);
}
void cleanUpSound(){
  // Clean up sources and buffers
  alDeleteSources(1, &source);
  alDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);
}
void playSound(){
  alSourcePlay(source);
}

void display(void){
  static int shouldPlaySound = 1;
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
  if(shouldPlaySound){
    loadSound();
    playSound();
    shouldPlaySound = 0;
  }else{
    ALuint state;
    alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    if(state != AL_PLAYING){
      cleanUpSound();
    }
  }
  glFlush ();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  // Initialize the environment
  alutInit(&argc,argv);
  // Capture errors
  alGetError();
  glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
  glutCreateWindow ("Greeting");
  //init ();
  glutDisplayFunc(display); 
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not just some arbitrary OpenAL command, but something that will read data from disk and block:

```
buffer = alutCreateBufferFromFile(FILENAME);
```

Such thing must not appear in the `display` function, since blocking there will prevent your render commands from being submitted. This causes the problem you described.

Also loading the sound data into the buffer is something that should need to be done *only once* anyway, not once every frame. You can play the same buffer from the same source (or other sources) a million times.
Also, you most certainly do not want to start playing a source every frame either (which is what you're doing right now).

Comment: Honestly, I think the loop that waits for the state to change from playing to not playing is what is blocking the longest. Disk I/O is pretty quick these days, but that loop will block for the duration of the audio file (which does not change with more efficient disk hardware).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Wow, you're right, I didn't even see that loop at the end. That one is even worse, since it's busy waiting (and, as you point out, probably waiting for a loooong time). The point about blocking on disk access is still true, though. Disk I/O is still some millisesconds _per access_ these days, and ALUT doesn't load the file in one single read. All in all, one can summarize that a lot of stuff is happinging in per-frame code that doesn't belong there (or even into the render thread).

Comment: Definitely, I did not mean to imply that loading the file came for free. However, it is possible to service a lot of (uncached) disk I/O events in under 10 ms, leaving 6.6 ms to draw the actual frame and still meet the 60 fps deadline many times. Audio file duration, on the other hand is measured in seconds usually rather than milliseconds. After all, in this program the only thing the OP is doing with GL is clearing the color / depth buffer, that can certainly be completed within 6 ms even on the worst of GPUs ;)